# How to hide a user property in ATG BCC UI using ViewMappingRepository

Tags: oracle, user-interface, atg, atg-dynamo, oracle-commerce

I am new to ViewMappingRepository. I need to hide one user property in ATG BCC user screen tab. how to hide the property? .

```
<property name="lastPurchasedCost" data-type="string" display-name="Last Purchased Cost" />
```

Comment: Describe and provide sample data with your question.

Comment: hi @AmanSinghRajpoot I have a one bcc screen 'external user'. under external user I have general tab. user general tab all the user properties are listed. if needed we can able to change user property value via bcc this screen.

<property name="lastPurchasedCost" data-type="string" display-name="Last Purchased Cost"  />

I need to hide this property in bcc screen using view mapping repository.

Comment: Is it required that you use view mapping for that? Why don't you use "hidden" attribute on property definition?

Comment: @pantuptus if we are set hidden="true" that property name will not be shown in user segment ruleset. that's why I'm hide this property via View mapping repository.

Answer (score 0):

First need to create a new attribute value for hide a property in ViewMappingRepository.

```
<add-item item-descriptor="attributeValue" id="AmAvHideUsersGeneralProp">
  <set-property name="value"><![CDATA[lastPurchasedCost]]></set-property>
</add-item>
```

My property is shown under the user general category. So print that category ItemViewMapping and update your created new attributeValue id set to excludedProperties value.

```
<add-item item-descriptor="itemViewMapping" id="AmIvmUsersGeneral">
  <set-property name="attributeValues"><![CDATA[excludedProperties=AmAvHideUsersGeneralProp]]></set-property>
</add-item>
```

Note: If already set any of the attributeValue to excludedProperties you need to add only you property name to the existing attributeValue inside set-property value.